# How to sanitize input with PHP and the sqlsrv driver?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-injection, sanitization

I'm working on a PHP MSSQL project that is using the sqlsrv driver.
What's the best way to stop SQL injection attacks? I need something like mysql_real_escape_string() but for sqlsrv driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is not to write your SQL so that you need to use an analogue of `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which you would do by using placeholders for the values and then passing the variables (that would otherwise have been handled by `mysql_real_escape_string()`) when you execute the statement or open the cursor or whatever.

Failing that, look at the output of `mysql_real_escape_string()`; it might be appropriate for MS SQL Server too.  It depends on how it does the escaping (and what escaping it does).

Answer (score 5):

If you use it like this, quoting is automatic:

```
$sql = "exec usp_cis_upd
        @key = ?,
        @value = ?";

$params = array(
    $key,
    trim($_POST["value"]));

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbh, $sql, $params);
```