# Is there a function similar to mysql_real_escape_string for php's sqlsrv library?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm am looking for a function similar to `mysql_real_escape_string` for the **SQLSRV** library.

Specifically I'm having difficulties escaping single quotation marks. Instead of escaping with a `"\"` like in **mysql** you use a single quote in front of the other single quote as the escape method.

I'm working on coming up with a solution of my own using `preg_replace` but was just wondering if there was something else out there I was missing.

Comment: I've found a solution using preg_replace
     `$pattern = "/'/";
 $replacement = "''";
 $output = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use an abstraction layer like http://php.net/pdo, http://www.doctrine-project.org/ or http://www.propelorm.org/

With pdo for example you can use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: That does look like one solution to my problem but all my code uses the sqlsrv library and it's working great with the exception of my single quotation problem. I really don't want to scrap that and start over with pdo just because of this one little issue.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604036/how-to-sanitize-input-with-php-and-the-sqlsrv-driver

Comment: and here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php

Comment: Thanks. The solutions you provided are very informative and since there is no alternative to mysql_real_escape_string for sqlsrv I am marking yours as the correct answer.

Comment: This is definetely not the correct answer. What is your recommendation if I want to write a custom abstraction layer? There may be cases where PDO or Doctrine are a good choice, but in some cases they are not.