# PHP - Query with Submit Button

Tags: php, sql, submit

Having troubles on why I am not getting a result. I don't get an error and it processes but no results show. Can anyone help me with this?

PHP

```
$sku= $_POST['sku'];
$sql = "SELECT sku
        FROM location_inventory
        WHERE (sku = 'sku')";
// SQLSRV Query
    $results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $results === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
echo '
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <th>Part Number</th>
        </tr>';
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

HTML

```
<BODY>
<form action="show.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <input type="text" value="Enter Part Number" name="sku" maxlength="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-family:Calibri">
            <input type="submit"  value="Search"/>
    </tr>
```

Comment: is that your HTML code? `<tr>` without `<table>`

Comment: can you also put your output in your question

Comment: Maybe you just don't have `ERROR_REPORTING` turned on in PHP? You should probably do so.

Comment: Did you test your Mysql connection.. ?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, As I am new I'm not afraid to ask. Every extra bit of information helps me in my quest to learn. Error Reporting has been turn on and is already helping me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT sku
    FROM location_inventory
    WHERE sku = '$sku'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Replace WHERE (sku = 'sku')"

With    WHERE (sku = $sku)";
```

Comment: I smell SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass $sku to your select string. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `sku` FROM `location_inventory` WHERE (`sku` = '" . $sku . "')";
```

Also make sure to escape all your inputs you use for your database queries, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669940/is-there-a-function-similar-to-mysql-real-escape-string-for-phps-sqlsrv-library) for more info.

Ah I forgot: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the start of your file to get all errors.

Comment: I added the error reporting line to my files and it's working like a charm. Already helping me. Thanks :) as soon as I can upvote it shall me done.

Answer (score 0):

Along with what sudhakar said, you should try outputting $row[0] instead of $row[1] since I'm guessing you will only have 1 row of data (if each sku is unique).

Comment: You are correct, Learning both SQL and PHP leaves me sometimes confused when starting at 0 or 1.